# Anaconda (Python36) error after installing ArcGIS: No module named 'arcpy'

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, installation, error, anaconda

I have a Anaconda with Python 3.6, and I installed the ArcGIS with the command

```
conda install -c esri arcgis
```

but when I went to test it presented the error:

> No module named 'arcpy'.

I saw the tutorials and I didn't find the file `Desktop10.3.pth` in the path `site-packages had a file called Desktop10.3.pth`. I didn't find in anywhere.

Comment: I know `arcgis` will use arcpy if its available. However `arcgis` AFAIK only works in Python 3.x Dont worry about the Desktop10.3 pth file, those would point at Python 2.7. In short, those shouldnt have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Can you confirm that you only have Anaconda (Python36), NOT ArcGIS Pro? Maybe its worth adding if you have ArcMap and what version.

Comment: Are you sure you imported arcpy before you called the module?

Comment: Desktop `arcpy` only works with Python 2.7.  If you want to use `arcpy` with Python 3 you need to install ArcGIS Pro. What you have installed is the "ArcGIS API for Python".

Comment: I not have ArcGIS Pro, but I'll install it. Thank you, guys

Answer (score 1):

In ESRI's `arcpy` documentation ["What is ArcPy"](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-arcpy-.htm) they make it sound like any other python package, but it is different than a other packages:

- Apparently `arcpy` is closed source and only available within ESRI.
- It seems to depend on ESRI's software
- `arcpy` is not installed in Python, it's added to the python path if you have ESRI installed.

The package appears to be an interface to a local installation of ESRI, not a python package that uses python.

My conjecture is based on several readings. The clearest hints were from the [blog](https://gisday.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/setting-up-anaconda-pysal-with-arcgis-python-environment/) of @Qiusheng-Wu. From this section about using Anaconda it seems clear that you're accessing python that's inside ESRI's program files:

> - Create a zconda.pth (path) file with the content “C:\Anaconda2\envs\arcpro\lib\site-packages” in it.
> - Then Copy zconda.pth to C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages

It's confusing because you can install the packages `esri` and `arcgis` without the ESRI software (i.e. they're normal packages), but the same is not true of `arcpy`.

It's also confusing because the ESRI documentation makes it sound like this is a general purpose package without dependencies.

@Luke's answer in the comments is correct, but I wanted to provide a bit more documentation and actual answer for future searchers.